# How to convert a column value into timestamp if it is integer, otherwise keep it as it is in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am running a SQL query for several tables.
All tables have a column called 'ts' which is INT64 in some tables and TIMESTAMP in other tables.
I have two sets of query which works for my tables

If ts data type = INT64 I run:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP_MICROS(ts) FROM myTable WHERE ...
```

If ts data type = timestamp I run:

```
SELECT ts FROM myTable WHERE ...
```

Is there any solution to combine these two queries into one query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is tricky, because BQ is rather strongly typed.  However, you can convert values to strings.  So the idea is to use a `case` expression, check the string value itself for the type, and then use the appropriate conversion to get a timestamp:

```
select (case when regexp_contains(cast(ts as string), '^[0-9]+$')
             then timestamp_seconds( cast(cast(ts as string) as int64) )
             else cast( cast(ts as string) as timestamp )
        end)
```

And, in fact, this expression works on both numbers and timestamps:

```
select (case when regexp_contains(cast(ts as string), '^[0-9]+$')
             then timestamp_seconds( cast(cast(ts as string) as int64) )
             else cast( cast(ts as string) as timestamp )
        end)
from (select 10000000000 as ts) x
union all
select (case when regexp_contains(cast(ts as string), '^[0-9]+$')
             then timestamp_seconds( cast(cast(ts as string) as int64) )
             else cast( cast(ts as string) as timestamp )
        end)
from (select current_timestamp as ts) x
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to this can be made using BigQuery's metadata to have a less verbose query:

```
select 
   if(
     m.data_type = 'INT64', 
     timestamp_micros(t.ts), 
     cast(t.ts as timestamp)
   ) as ts
from 
   mydataset.mytable t
left join 
   `[my_project_id].mydataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` on 1=1
where 
   table_name = '[my_table_name]' and column_name = 'ts'
```